# How to use AngularJS on a WebServices project

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I'm currently working (as a school project, nothing real) on a REST WebServices to handle a little chat system. The WebServices tier is done, but now I have to add an administration panel to allow users to manage their databases (conversations registered, message, etc).

I would like to know how to implement this using Angular JS.

Should I add the features needed on my WebServices, or should I create some new controller in the ASP.NET project just for this ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **your AngularJS project supposed to be front-end** system which contains UI & logic code to make calls to web service and your webservice project (I don't know whether you choose WCF/Web API/ASMX or anything) supposed to be the **back-end** system which will expose some HTTP endpoints (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) for your **front-end** system to call. I would suggest you to separate these two projects so that you can have clearer view about how two of them communicate with each other.

For the second part of your question, now you want to use AngularJS to call your webservice. The most common way is **$http (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)**. Just put the code inside your event handler (button clicked or submitted) and it should be working.

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You would create an html form that uses ng-model on the text fields to represent your back end models. Next you will need a controller to send those models via a service that will interact with your rest web services to persist your data. I'm actually working on several applications like this currently but they have a node.js based back end instead of .Net but the format for sending and retrieving data is json.